# Reading a datetime value from a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

How can I read datetime fields from a SQL database?

This is not working:

```
emp.DateFacturation = (DateTime)(dr["DateFacturation"])
```

nor is this:

```
emp.DateFacturation = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateFacturation"].toString());
```

Comment: what is the data type of `DateFacturation`?

Comment: What is the value of `dr["DateFacturation"]`

Comment: public DateTime DateFacturation { get; set; }

Comment: "Doesn't work" is very vague. What's the error?

Answer (score 7):

Since you've commented a now deleted answer with:

> dr is a DataReader

You can use [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx). You should check first if the value is `DBNull` with [`DataReader.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx):

```
DateTime dateFacturation;
int colIndex = dr.GetOrdinal("DateFacturation");
if(!dr.IsDBNull( colIndex ))
    dateFacturation = dr.GetDateTime( colIndex );
```

I use [`GetOrdinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx) to get the column index of the column name to pass it to `GetDateTime`.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote but can you explain why this would work over the non-working examples the OP posted?

Comment: @JoeyGennari: You're right. I've edited my answer since i assume that this column can be null.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
DateTime datevalue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dr["DateFacturation"].ToString(), out datevalue))
{
    emp.DateFacturation = datevalue;              
}
else
{
    // TODO: conversion failed... not a valid DateTime
    // Print it out and see what is wrong with it...
}
```